# How to get the list of available categories in HERE API?

Tags: here-api

Here api provides in their documentation a list of categories [category list](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics/place_categories/places-category-system.html) that can be used to filter places. I want to obtain this list automatically to show that to the user in the front-end.

I try to search in the documentation [here](https://developer.here.com/documentation#services) but I couldn't fine and api enpoint to retrieve the list of available categories.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using a filter like this -  https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/
browse
?at=41.93088,12.46803
&limit=5
&categories=300-3000-0025,300-3100,550-5510-0202,500-5520,600-6100-0062
&apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}
More about it is mentioned here - https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-browse-brief.html